# Remove margin around text

Tags: css

I want to remove the margin around a #header. It should be the same slim margin as in the #content box. In the first place, I do not understand, why #header and #content have different margins.

Any pointers are appreciate

```css
#box {
  background-color: lightgreen;
}

#header {
  background-color: grey;
  float: right;
  width: 150px;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
}

#content {
  background-color: lightblue;
  clear: both;
}
```

```html
<div id="box">
  <div id="header">
    <p>Header</p>
  </div>
  <div id="content">Content</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/datvLg9r/1/

Comment: By default `p` elements have margin.

Comment: Ok, I just need to remove/define them in `p`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to remove the space between inline-block elements?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<p></p>` Tag have margin so you have to set `margin:0` for p element.

Answer (score 0):

This targets the p element within the div with id header only and removes the margin.

```
 #header p {
    margin: 0;
  }
```

see demo https://jsfiddle.net/datvLg9r/1/

Answer (score 0):

update HTML as follow - remove p element it will work.

```
<div id="box">

<div id="header">Header
</div>

<div id="content">Content</div>

</div>
```